# Incorrect number of dimensions while using R.Update

Tags: r, statistics, probability

I'm a very new R user. I teach my self to use it but I still make many mistakes :(

I'm trying to run this code but I have an error in the Y_dina function. I hope someone can explain what is the error and how to fix it.

```
Y_dina <- function(Alpha,q_m,s,g){
 for(i in 1:N)  
 {
    j_index = sample(50,1:J,replace=FALSE)
    for(j in 1:length(j_index))
    {
    s=runif(J,0.05, 0.25)
   g=runif(J,0.05, 0.25)
     u <- runif(1)
     
    eta = prod(Alpha[i,]^q_m[j_index[j,]])

 return(as.numeric((u>s[j])^eta*((u<g[j]))^(1-eta)))

       }
   }
   }
```

I already define Alpha matrix and q_m matrix, each time I run the code I have the same error: Error in Alpha[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions. While the alpha as the following:

```
K=4
N=10000
J=200
    Alpha = rep(0,K)
       for(j in 1:K){
           temp_m = combn(1:K,m=j)
           temp_mat = matrix(0,ncol(temp_m),K)
           for(j in 1:ncol(temp_m)) temp_mat[j,temp_m[,j]] = 1
           Alpha = rbind(Alpha,temp_mat)
       }
       Alpha = as.matrix(Alpha)
```

and,

```
 q_m = matrix(rep(diag(K),2),K,K,byrow=TRUE)
       for(i in 2:K)
       {
           temp_m = combn(1:K,m=i)
           temp_mat = matrix(0,ncol(temp_m),K)
           for(j in 1:ncol(temp_m)) temp_mat[j,temp_m[,j]] = 1
           q_m = rbind(q_m,temp_mat)
       }
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Something to help focus the investigation -- after constructing Alpha, does it look the way you expect? I think you should paste whatever you get for Alpha into your problem description, as it will help others understand the problem, and therefore help them help you.

Comment: @H85 please check my answer

Comment: you need to declare the K before the Y_dina function or declaring alpha also, there was a typo in the code, where you are assigning value to eta.

Comment: Please declare N as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    N= 10000
    J=200
    K=4
    Alpha = rep(0,K)
    for(j in 1:K){
      temp_m = combn(1:K,m=j)
      temp_mat = matrix(0,ncol(temp_m),K)
      for(j in 1:ncol(temp_m)) temp_mat[j,temp_m[,j]] = 1
      Alpha = rbind(Alpha,temp_mat)
    }
    Alpha = as.matrix(Alpha)

    Y_dina <- function(Alpha,q_m,s,g){
      for(i in 1:N)  
      {
        j_index = as.numeric(sample(50,1:J,replace=FALSE))#step1
        for(j in 1:length(j_index))
        {
          s=runif(J,0.05, 0.25)
          g=runif(J,0.05, 0.25)
          u <- runif(1)
          eta = prod(Alpha[i,]^q_m[j_index[j,]])#step2
          return(as.numeric((u>s[j])^eta*((u<g[j]))^(1-eta)))
        }
      }
    }
```

From the code itself, you are assigning Alpha a matrix.in step1,j_index is generating a random value which needs to be converted to numeric.

In step2, you are assigning a product value which is matrix multiplication of q_m and alpha. Hence both matrices should be following matrix multiplication. The example you are giving both the matrices is 1x4 hence, they cant perform matrix multiplication.

Dimensions of alpha are [1:16,1:4] and Dimensions of q_m are [1:15,1:4] when I run your code. That may possibly the reason why you are getting incorrect dimensions.

Comment: If I send these values to Y_dina(c(1,0,0,1),c(1,1,1,1),0.05,0.06) I still have the same error: Error in Alpha[i, ] : incorrect number of dimensions

Comment: N is also not declared in your code.and the Alpha is in form of matrix,so you need to change that as well.Please declare N and let me know.

Comment: I already declared N= 10000 and J=200, K=4 in the beginning of the code. Alpha should be a matrix from (0,0,0,0) to (1,1,1,1). the column number is K

Comment: So, in step2 if I have single Item it will be like: eta <- function(alpha,q_m){return(prod(alpha^q_m))}. What about my case for J items, how should I write it?

Comment: Dimensions of alpha are [1:16,1:4] and Dimensions of q_m are [1:15,1:4] when I run your code..That may possibly the reason why you are getting incorrect dimensions

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much for your helping and your time. It means a lot to me.